# Calendar in the header of a DataGridView in any column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, calendar

Is it possible to add calendar picker in the header of the DataGridView in any of the column ?

Something like this:

[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

I managed such an effect similar to Excel Filter in this way.

Obviously you have to build your calendar control.
Using WPF DataGrid is all easier.

If you want this affect you can try to implement this event in DataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        DataGridView dg = (DataGridView)sender;
        BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dg.DataSource;

        //TODO;
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {        
        FrmMyCalendar f = new FrmMyCalendar();
        f.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);

        //TODO   
    }
}
```

You can think of introducing grids WPF slowly through ElementHost

Answer (score 0):

Yes... It's possible

```
DateTimePicker dtPicker;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtPicker = new DateTimePicker();
    dtPicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    dtPicker.Visible = false;
    dtPicker.Width = 100;
    dgT.Controls.Add(dtPicker);
    dtPicker.ValueChanged += this.dtPicker_ValueChanged;
    dgT.CellBeginEdit += this.dgT_CellBeginEdit;
    dgT.CellEndEdit += this.dgT_CellEndEdit;
}

private void dgT_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ((dgT.Focused) && (dgT.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2))   // Here you can define on which column DateTimePicker will be activated
        {
            dtPicker.Location = dgT.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location;
            dtPicker.Visible = true;

            if (dgT.CurrentCell.Value != DBNull.Value)
            {
                dtPicker.Value = (DateTime)dgT.CurrentCell.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                dtPicker.Value = DateTime.Today;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dtPicker.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void dgT_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ((dgT.Focused) && (dgT.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2))
        {
            dgT.CurrentCell.Value = dtPicker.Value.Date;                       
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void dtPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgT.CurrentCell.Value = dtPicker.Text;
}

private void dgT_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    dtPicker.Visible = false;
}
```

Just put `DataGridView` on the form a. In my case I named it `dgT`.